# Webpage too big

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm working on a homework for my Software Engineering class and I'm trying to make a mockup of a  webpage using HTML and CSS. I've gotten close to it but my one problem is that my webpage is too wide and I'm not sure if I have to size down all the pictures and text or the webpage itself. Here is my CSS code:

Also here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Airbnb</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Meet Guidebooks</h1>
  <P>Discover hundreds of local sports recommended by Airbnb hosts </P>
  <div class="Top1">
  <img src="img/san-francisco.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="Sanf">San Francisco</div>
  <div class= "Top2">
  <img src="img/new-york.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="NY">New York</div>
  <div class="Top3">
  <img src="img/london.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="Lon">London</div>
  <button id="Guide">See All Guidebooks</button>
  <h3>Just for the weekend</h3>
  <p>Discover new, inspiring places close to home.</p>
<div class="Bottom1">
<img src="img/napa.jpg">
</div>
<div id="Napa">Napa</div>
</div>
<div class="Bottom2">
  <img src="img/sonoma.jpg">
</div>
<div id="Son">Sonoma</div>
<div class="Bottom3">
  <img src="img/san-francisco-2.jpg">
</div>
<div id="San2">San Francisco</div>
  <button id="Destinations">See All Destinations</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
}




h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}

p{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 color: grey;
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}

html, body {
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.Top1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Top2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 420px;
  left: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.Top3 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 880px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.Bottom1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 900px;
  right: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.Bottom2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1625px;
  left: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.Bottom3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 950px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#Sanf {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 235px;
 right: 450px;
 color: white;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: "Monsterrat", sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#NY {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 675px;
  left: 855px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Monsterrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#Lon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1135px;
  left: 1495px;
  margin: auto 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Monsterrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#Napa {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1235px;
    left: 270px;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Monsterrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#Son {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1965px;
  left: 950px;
  margin: auto 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Monsterrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#San2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2690px;
  left: 1600px;
  margin: auto 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Monsterrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#Guide{
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 900px;
  left: 650px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: "Monsterrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: grey;
}

#Destinations{ 
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2350px;
  left: 700px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  height: 30px;
  //font-family: sans-serif;//
  font-weight: bold;
  color: grey;
}
```

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY5Nh.jpg)

Comment: Your HTML & CSS is not close to the screenshot. The webpage is too wide because you are using `left`, `right` the wrong way. It might be easier to use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to create the layout for you.

Comment: In case that you don't want to depend on something like Bootstrap or you want to create everything on your own, you can learn more about [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries for each specific size you want and adjust the elements based on that size:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1050px){
   .img{
      width:2rem;
     }
    .text{
      font-size:1rem;
     }
 }
```